# Display Dropdown values from checkbox in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I need your help with the following situation:
I have a dropdownlist as follows:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="myvalues" runat="server">
<listitem value="Low">Low</listitem>
<listitem value="Medium">Medium</listitem>
<listitem value="High">High</listitem>
<listitem value="Super High">Super High</listitem>
</dropdownlist>
```

I need to call the above dropdown values from a checkbox as follows:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="mybox" runat="server" Text="Click Me" Checked="true"/>
```

When I save the values, it works fine, but when I call the edit it display the first value only. I would like to bring the value saved, I also need to code in VB.Net
I have tried the following but didn't work:

```
If mybox.checked = True Then
'myvalues.SelectedValue = true
 myvalues.Items(myvalues.Items.Count -1).Selected = True
else
'to do somethig here'
End If
```

The problem is that when I try to edit, it brigs only the first dropdown value, which is **Low** not the saved one.
Can Anyone help me with matter?
I'd like to thank in advance for your great support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `If` statement you are doing this:

`myvalues.SelectedValue = true`

I think you meant:

```
myvalues.SelectedValue = "Super High"    'or whatever dropdown value you saved
```

Comment: Actually, I want to display any of the four values from the dropdownlist.  When I am editing, I would like to see the value I saved, which can be Low, medium, High or Super High. Can you help me with this matter? thanks

Comment: You are setting the SelectedValue of your dropdown to true instead of the value you say you have saved, so the dropdown is showing the first item in your list as selected by default. That's my best guess based on the minimal code provided.

Comment: I know this is not right, what I would like to do is just use an If statement to call the saved value.

Comment: I have tried the code I just edited on the If statement, but still is not working